# Android Development - How can GestureDetectorCompat class Object used for detecting gesture methods from GestureDetector class

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity, android-event, android-gesture

I was going through some tutorials for detecting common gesture and saw the code given below. Here, `GestureDetectorCompat` Object is made to detect the gestures using the event handler `SetOnDoubleTapListener`. The main activity class implements two interfaces from `GestureDetector` class - `OnGestureListener` and `OnDoubleTapListener`. I got few question,

1) How came `GestureDetectorCompat` object is used to create the event handler `SetOnDoubleTapListener` for the callback methods inside of `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` and `GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener` interfaces since `GestureDetectorCompat` and `GestureDetector` are two different class and how is it working fine with it.

2) Is `SetOnDoubleTapListener` Event Handler method can be used for all the callback methods inside the `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` and `GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener` interfaces? If yes why they named it `SetOnDoubleTapListener`?

3) Why `GesutureDetector` class can't have just one interface consist of all the methods defined inside of `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` and `GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener` interfaces.

4) Whats the difference between `GestureDetector` and `GestureDetectorCompat`? Why `GestureDetectorCompat` class don't have any interface defined.

Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector; 

// Called when the activity is first created. 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Instantiate the gesture detector with the
    // application context and an implementation of
    // GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
    // Set the gesture detector as the double tap
    // listener.
    mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
}

@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) { 
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"onDown: " + event.toString()); 
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, 
        float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onLongPress: " + event.toString()); 
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onScroll: " + e1.toString()+e2.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onShowPress: " + event.toString());
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapUp: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTapEvent: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}
```

}